# how best to break page using CSS in this case page-break property doesn`t work for me

Tags: php, html, css

I have an ID card printing system  responsible for printing staff IDs its designed to print  front and back sides of the card  in one browser page  side by side I want to achieve print each side separate browser page so that my printer will recognize the second page as a backside "the page-break in CSS" is not working for me.

```
    #id {
        width: 297px;
        height: 475px;
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0.88;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        transition: 0.4s;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        page-break-after: always;
        
        
    }

    #id::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: url('images/IDCARD.png');
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-size: 297px 475px;
        opacity: ;
        z-index: -2;
        text-align: center;
        page-break-after:always;
        

    }

    .container {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: sans-serif;

    }

    .id-1 {
       
        transition: 0.4s;
        width: 297px;
        height: 475px;
        background: url('images/ID1.png');
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        float: left;
        margin: auto;
        margin-left: 300px;
        border-radius: 1%;
      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks very good and organized couldn't find error in yours .I might recommend you to try executing each block one by one or try using other laptop incase if didn't work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).